# What am I doing wrong with Angular 2 forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am trying to create simple reactive form with angular 2

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule 
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="submit($event)">
      <div>
        <label>login</label>
        <input formControllName="login" type="text">
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>password</label>
        <input formControllName="password" type="text">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <p>{{ loginForm.value | json }}</p>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
      login: [""],
      password: [""]
    })
  }

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.loginForm.value)
  }
}
```

When I fill inputs and click "submit" the loginForm value is still with initial values. Besides it doesnt change while I filling inputs.
Example is supersimple, but it doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is link to plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/aMuYuRXMlTsox4TklHIg?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelled `formControllName` - extra `l`

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I apologize, I did not see a typo and spent a couple of hours on it, checking various options and theories. I was in despair.